# Can $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM be interpreted as describing a superconductor?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, supersymmetry, superconductivity, duality

I am quite fond of analogies between QFT and statistical mechanics, although I am not at all an expert in statistical physics. And I was wondering if it would make any sense to view the (Euclidean) action of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM as describing a $4$d superconductor in the context of the Landau-Ginzburg model. [Wikipedia says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginzburg%E2%80%93Landau_theory) that the Landau-Ginzburg free energy is given by:

$$F = F_n + \alpha \left| \phi \right|^2 + \frac{\beta}{2} \left| \phi \right|^4 + \frac{1}{2m} \left| \left(\ i \hbar \nabla - 2 e \bf{A} \right) \phi \right|^2 + \frac{\left| \bf{B} \right|}{2 \mu_0}. \tag{1}$$

Meanwhile, the relevant part of the action of $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM reads:

$$S_\text{YM} \sim \frac{1}{g^2} \int d^4 x\ \left\lbrace \left(\partial_\mu \phi_i^a + f^{abc} A_\mu^b \phi_i^c \right)^2 + \frac{1}{2} f^{abe} f^{cde} \phi_i^a \phi_j^b \phi_i^c \phi_j^d + i f^{abc} \bar{\psi}^a \Gamma_i \phi_i^b \psi^c + ...\right\rbrace , \tag{2}$$

where I omitted all terms not containing a $\phi$, and in particular the kinetic terms of $A_\mu$ and $\psi$.

What I want to do now is to compare both theories. The fourth term of $(1)$ contains the kinetic term with the covariant derivative (if I am not mistaken), which can also be found in $(2)$. The third term is a $\phi^4$-term, and we also have that in $(2)$.

There is nothing like the second term though, but since it is a quadratic term it could maybe be absorbed in the covariant derivative, or we ccouldn set $\alpha = 0$? Maybe that is a weak point of what I am trying to show, as this term seems to imply a massive theory. On another hand, in the [usual Landau model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_theory#Ising_model_example) the quadratic terms just have a parameter $r$ in front of them so can I not just "pack everything together" there?

There is still one more term that can be found this time in $(2)$ but not in $(1)$, which is the Yukawa interaction. Since it has only one power of $\phi$, it could maybe be interpreted as coupling the theory to an external field, i.e. something like

$$F(\phi) \to F(\phi) + H \phi. \tag{3}$$

(like in the Landau theory again) So now we have a complete analogy between the $\phi$-terms of $(1)$ and $(2)$.

So I was wondering:

1. does it make sense to think that way, and if yes how would you interpret the different fields and colors ($A_\mu^a$, $\psi^a$) on the statistical physics side?
2. In usual Landau theory $\phi$ represents a spin field, and I think I would find It convenient to think of $\phi$ in that way. But what is $\phi$ in Landau-Ginzburg theory exactly? Wikipedia is vague about that ("no direct interpretation of this parameter was given in the original paper").
3. In $\mathcal{N}=4$ SYM it is common to work with $1/2$-BPS operators of the form $\mathcal{O}_k (x) \sim\ \text{Tr}\ \phi^k (x)$. What would be the interpretation on the statistical physics side of a correlator $\left\langle \mathcal{O}_k (x) \mathcal{O}_k(y) \right\rangle$?